# SQLServer/SSIS - Select with JOIN using dynamic table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to do a select that change table from join dynamically and the table ( DataGenerated ) is based last number from UserId.

Example: if UserId ends with 2, i'll look in DataGenerated_2. If UserId ends with 3, i'll  look in DataGenerated_3. If it ends with 0, i'll look in DataGenerated.

I'm trying to make a select clause but i'm stuck and i didn't find how to change table name during sql execution.

My SQL only works  for UserId's that ends with 0.

```
SELECT e.UserId, COUNT(e.UserId) FROM Campaign c 
LEFT JOIN DataGenerated e ON c.UserId = e.UserId
WHERE e.Status = 2 and c.ExportDate IS NULL
GROUP BY e.UserId;
```

If i make 10 queries ( because table goes 0 to _9 ) and use union all, i can do what i want but i'm trying to find better way to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is sp_executesql an option for you maybe? http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: I'd test the union versus using dynamic sql as cproinger mentioned above.  In my experience, using union was always more efficient.       Obviously, if possible you should combine these tables into one table with a field to differentiate the userid.

Comment: of course you are right Dave.Gugg (expect for maybe an 0.0000000001 % edge case maybe), i guess i didn't read the question carefully enough. If there is a finite number of tables to query from you do not need a dynamic query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could work with a Cursor:
        CREATE TABLE #TEST(
    UserID int)

```
INSERT INTO #TEST
VALUES
(0),
(1),
(2)

CREATE TABLE #DataGenerated_1(
a int)

CREATE TABLE #DataGenerated_2(
b int)

CREATE TABLE #DataGenerated(
c int)

DECLARE @User int,@Query nvarchar(50)

DECLARE C_Table CURSOR
FOR
SELECT UserID FROM #TEST
OPEN C_Table

FETCH NEXT FROM C_Table INTO @User
While (@@Fetch_status = 0)
BEGIN

IF @User <> 0
BEGIN
SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM #DataGenerated_'+CONVERT(nvarchar(1),@User)
END

ELSE
BEGIN
SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM #DataGenerated'
END

EXEC (@Query)

FETCH NEXT FROM C_Table INTO @User
END

CLOSE C_Table
DEALLOCATE C_Table

DROP TABLE #TEST
DROP TABLE #DataGenerated
DROP TABLE #DataGenerated_1
DROP TABLE #DataGenerated_2
```

Hope this is what you want
Have a nice day

Etienne